# Magento edit the 'items' table in order emails

Tags: magento

I'm using magento 1.6.  I'd like to edit the table of items that appears in every order email.  Where can I find the template for this?

More specifically, under 'product name' I want to add my custom attribute named 'subtitle'.

If you know where the template is I should be able to work out the rest.

Comment: I found the template myself.  But I am now stuck on getting the attributes to display. The file is located at /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId())->getdata('subtitle');

s the code I'm using to try and get my 'subtitle' attribute to display, but so far no luck.  It says 'Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();    
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku());
```

instead of $this->getProduct(). Than You can use $_product->getSubtitle();